# PowerShell dir show all symlink targets like Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, symlink

When you use `dir` in Command Prompt `cmd.exe` you get

```
C:\path\to\somewhere> dir
2022-10-03  20:17    <DIR>          .
2022-10-03  19:54    <DIR>          ..
2022-10-03  20:16    <SYMLINKD>     link [..\target\]
```

But when you try the same in PowerShell you get

```
PS C:\path\to\somewhere> dir
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----l        2022-10-03     20:16                link
```

How do you make PowerShell also show all the link targets inside a directory like Command Prompt?

Comment: `cmd /c dir`, not sure why you want to do such a thing

Comment: lol, not bad actually. can't believe I didn't think of that earlier. add it as an answer please

Comment: The answer only shows how to get the `Target` on PS 5+. If you're using PS 4 it's probably easiest to stick with `cmd /c dir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the Powershell version. Remember that `dir` is just an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, and pre-PS 5, GCI simply didn't include properties for `linktype` or `target`.

For PS 5+, this works:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\" -Force |
   Where-Object { $_.LinkType -ne $null } |
   ft FullName,Attributes,Linktype,Target

FullName                  Attributes LinkType     Target
--------                  ---------- --------     ------
C:\temp\hard Directory, ReparsePoint SymbolicLink {C:\Temp\temp\text.txt}
C:\temp\j    Directory, ReparsePoint Junction     {c:\temp\tmp\actss}
C:\temp\soft Directory, ReparsePoint SymbolicLink {C:\Temp\Log4j}
```

For PS 4, with no `Linktype` we need to check ReparsePoints for a match and we only get the output below:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\" -Force |
   Where-Object { $_.LinkType -ne $null -or $_.Attributes -match "ReparsePoint" } |
   ft FullName,Attributes,Linktype,Target -auto

FullName                  Attributes Linktype Target
--------                  ---------- -------- ------
C:\temp\J    Directory, ReparsePoint
C:\temp\soft Directory, ReparsePoint
C:\temp\hard   Archive, ReparsePoint
```

So in the latter instance, you're best off shelling out to `cmd /c dir` as mentioned previously.

Comment: you should use `$_.Attributes -band "ReparsePoint"` since the property is a Flags enum

Comment: That's true! I use `cmd /c dir` on the rare occasions I want to do something like that on a legacy OS, And I just noticed I have the wrong output pasted in that part.

Comment: Actually, I think that matches on the string in the Where clause, not the flags as such. Someone can enjoy experimenting with that if they choose.

Comment: It is not a string it's an enum. Why would a string have a `.HasFlag` method ?

Comment: I don't know? It looks like it's passing back a string in the formatted output to GCI. I literally just tried it on a 2012 R2 box and got this error when I tried a `-band "ReparsePoint"` : `Cannot convert value "ReparsePoint" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."` Yes, `$_.Attributes.GetType()` gives us a basetype of `System.Enum`, but it looks like an implicit `.tostring()` in the output. If we were doing a proper `-filter` rather than a crappy `Where-Object` on the returned output, we'd probably need the `-band` plus integer value.

Comment: `$_.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint` or `$_.Attributes.HasFlag([IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint)` should work properly in older versions

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon -match works too, it just converts attributes to a string.

Comment: @js2010 I know it works, doesnt mean its the proper way to do it

Comment: Mate, it was a quick-and-dirty example illustrating a method that I specifically said was *not useful* on legacy OSes. I even did the courtesy of briefly checking your suggested "fix" to the query. But it *doesn't matter* how efficient a correctly-formed query is on larger file systems if it's not going to **output** the desired result. Which it won't in PS 4 with no `LinkType` property, therefore not wasting my time further.

Comment: Nice, though it's worth pointing that "PS 5+" refers to _Windows PowerShell_ only. By contrast, the cross-platform, install-on-demand [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition (v6+, currently at v7.2.6) _does_show symlink / junction targets by default, albeit not in the exact same format as `cmd.exe`.